# JQuery mobile icons missing

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have problems with displaying icons in a popup.

Here is a fragment of my code:

**head:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Main Page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

**Popup with the button (button is not displayed just text):**

```html
<div  id="highscores" data-role="popup" class="ui-content" data-theme="e" data-overlay-theme="a"  style="min-width:400px">
  <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="star" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1> Summary </h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <p> Your results are shown below </p>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Correct: </td>
        <td id="correctTd"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Incorrect: </td>
        <td id="incorrectTd"> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ratio: </td>
        <td id="ratioTd"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</head>
```

How should I proceed with it?

**Firefox log:**

```
[15:21:22.120] GET
http://uwf.edu/CDE/MobileWeb/ajax.cfc?method=getOptions&_cf_ajaxproxytoken=74929DDA92ACB52984&returnFormat=json&argumentCollection=%7B%22questionId%22%3A1%7D&_cf_nodebug=true&_cf_nocache=true&_cf_clientid=80E1FEFCAEF84777C986F41BD95A9374&_cf_rc=1
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 23ms]
    --
    [15:21:47.964] GET http://uwf.edu/cde/mobileweb/selfcheck.cfm [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1465ms]
    [15:21:49.457] GET http://uwf.edu/cfscripts/ajax/messages/cfmessage_en_US_.js [HTTP/1.1
304 Not Modified 2ms]
    [15:21:49.458] GET http://uwf.edu/cfscripts/ajax/package/cfajax.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 2ms]
    [15:21:49.459] GET http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css
[HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 30ms]
    [15:21:49.460] GET http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 240ms]
    [15:21:49.460] GET http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js
[HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 30ms]
    [15:21:49.461] GET http://uwf.edu/cde/mobileweb/js/script.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 14ms]
    [15:21:49.462] GET http://uwf.edu/cde/MobileWeb/css/style.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 10ms]
    [15:21:49.712] Empty string passed to getElementById(). @ http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js:2
    [15:21:49.776] Setting Video
    [15:21:49.776] Resource id is undefined.
    [15:21:49.820] GET http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/images/ajax-loader.gif [HTTP/1.1
304 Not Modified 195ms]
    [15:21:49.821] GET http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/images/icons-18-white.png
[HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 443ms]
    [15:21:49.822] GET http://uwf.edu/CDE/MobileWeb/ajax.cfc?method=getOptions&_cf_ajaxproxytoken=74929DDA92ACB52984&returnFormat=json&argumentCollection=%7B%22questionId%22%3A3%7D&_cf_nodebug=true&_cf_nocache=true&_cf_clientid=80E1FEFCAEF84777C986F41BD95A9374&_cf_rc=0
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 504ms]
```

Comment: +1 For an excellent question.

Comment: The whole close button doesn't appear or star icon?

Comment: I tried with 'star' and 'delete' 
I can see only text 'close' in a place where I should see the button.

Comment: Other icons appear normally on the page?

Comment: Yes. I have a navbar with buttons and icons are displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `rel="external"` to your anchor tag may fix the issue.